# Want to create a navigation bar from list item which redirects to another page or document

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, splistitem, hyperlink, spfield

Navigation bar should get populated from List items(Hyperlink items) that maps to pages or another document.

Share Point 2010

Answer (score 0):

First find your way to Navigation Settings – start with Site settings > Look and feel > Navigation > Global Navigation setting.

Use Radio button to enable the site to use its own Top Link bar and not inherit it from parent site. Then tick the check box for SharePoint Server 2010 to automatically display the new pages in the site

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my requirement is to populate the navigation bars from list item and the list item should hold the reference to another page or Document on the site.